# How to avoid increasing ldf while transferring big data?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on my laptop for my study.

I have a table that has 150 million records.

I have to insert these records into another table.

While doing this process after around 2 hours I get my 150GB harddisk full notification.

when I check created files I see that .ldf size around 120GB while .mdf file around 30GB

I googled and found that ldf is the transaction log.

How can stop this file from creating or empty it during the process of insertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of below options to reduce the log file growth:

- You can go for SELECT * INTO to load to another table. It is minimally logged operation.
- If possible, You can change the recovery model to simple for reducing the amount of log generated

Alternatively, if you want to keep the recovery model as Full, want to recover from the current scenario, then you can do below things to free up space:

1. Take backup of the log to free up the log file size. *Safer approach, in case something goes wrong with full backup in next step, you can restore from the log backup and last available full backup.*
2. Take Full backup of the database.
3. Once you take Full backup of database, you can delete the log backup taken in step no. 1